# virtual memory in linux

Tags: linux, memory, virtual

I am debugging one issue where a same program behaves differently on different Linux boxes (all 2.6 kernels).  Basically on some linux box, mmap() of 16MB always succeeds, but on other linux box the same mmap() would fail with "ENOMEM".

I checked /proc//maps and saw the virtual memory map on different linux boxes are quite different. One thing is:  the address range for heap:

```
linux box1: the mmap() would return address of 31162000-31164000
linux box2: the mmap() would return address of a9a67000-a9a69000
```

My question is:  for a particular process, how is linux virtual memory arranged?  What decides the actual address ranges?  Why the mmap() would fail even I can still see some large unused virtual address ranges?

UPDATE:  here is an example of address space where mmap() of 16MB would fail:

```
10024000-10f6b000 rwxp 10024000 00:00 0 [heap]
30000000-3000c000 rw-p 30000000 00:00 0 
3000c000-3000d000 r--s 00000000 00:0c 5461 /dev/shm/mymap1
3000d000-3000e000 rw-s 00001000 00:0c 5461 /dev/shm/mymap2
3000e000-30014000 r--s 00000000 00:0c 5463 /dev/shm/mymap3
30014000-300e0000 r--s 00000000 00:0c 5465 /dev/shm/mymap4
300e0000-310e0000 r--s 00000000 00:0b 2554 /dev/mymap5
310e0000-31162000 rw-p 310e0000 00:00 0 
31162000-31164000 rw-s 00000000 00:0c 3554306 /dev/shm/mymap6
31164000-312e4000 rw-s 00000000 00:0c 3554307 /dev/shm/mymap7
312e4000-32019000 rw-s 00000000 00:0c 3554309 /dev/shm/mymap8
7f837000-7f84c000 rw-p 7ffeb000 00:00 0 [stack]
```

in the above example:  there are still big space between the last mymap8  and [stack]. But further mmap() of 16MB would fail.  My question is:  how does Linux decide mmap() base and the allowed range?

Thanks.

Comment: Linux does random address mapping for security so that explains the different virtual memory arrangements (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: thanks. That explains the address differences. However, I still don't understand why mmap() on some linux box would fail. Please see updated  question for the example.

Comment: Can you post some code. It sounds like you have a bug.